# How to write 日付 in romaji?

Tags: rōmaji

Looking at the google translator I find:

```
日付  (Hidzuke): Date
```

But when I try to write the same letter, it doesn't pop up kanji

Which all characters are used to write it?

Comment: If it helps, the kana is ひづけ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two common systems for writing romaji, one used by native Japanese to make typing easier, and one used by foreigners to make reading easier. In the Japanese system, (for example to form the correct kanji on a Japanese keyboard) 日付 would be written "hiduke". For foreigners, it's spelled "hizuke", which makes it easier to reproduce a mostly accurate sound, but gives the wrong hiragana on a Japanese keyboard.